# The script is running but nothing is being written to the logs

Tags: bash

The script is pretty long. Some parts of it are being writtent to the log, some are not, or the part that were written can stop appearing when I start the script the second time. It's impossible to tell.

In the last start  nothing was written at all.

It is important to note that in CLI it shows that the script is still running. And it can even finish and show results. But there are always big chunks of logs missing.

Example of the log.

```
2017-02-07 22:34:08,984 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 35%, Cumulative CPU 399.27 sec
2017-02-07 22:34:10,082 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 55%, Cumulative CPU 513.1 sec
2017-02-07 22:34:11,185 Stage-1 m









2017-02-07 22:34:58,625 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 724.42 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 12 minutes 4 seconds 420 msec
Ended Job = job_1479912084949_968905
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 74  Reduce: 100   Cumulative CPU: 724.91 sec   HDFS Read: 1117905 HDFS Write: 20080 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 12 minutes 4 seconds 910 msec
OK
```

I first thought it has something to do with the windows line endings. But after changing them everything remained the same.

example of code not being written in the log.

```
yeasterday_with_dash=2017-02-04
today_without_dash=20170205

echo "yeasterday_with_dash="$yeasterday_with_dash
echo "today_without_dash="$today_without_dash
```

this is how I start the script

```
bash start_fair_usage.sh >> LOGS/log201702052 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. It was eiter because I didn't add

```
#!/bin/bash
```

in the begining or magic. I think the second is at fault. It doesn't make me feel like an idiot.

Edit 09-02-2017

Everything seemed to be working fine some time, but recently it happened again. So, no it wasn't because of #!/bin/bash or windows line ending. Only one thing to say. Magic.

Edit 10.02.2017

I actually thought of another reason. I am writing logs to a disc. A lot of people have access to this disc and write something there. When there is no space, nothing is being written to the file.